# Spring Boot 1.4 @DataJpaTest - Error creating bean with name 'dataSource'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I've created a new spring boot 1.4 application, want to try some testing using @DataJpaTest but keep getting the following error message

*Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.*

**src/main/resources/application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_db
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**MyRepositoryTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
final public class MyRepositoryTest {
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web',
            'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa',
            'mysql:mysql-connector-java',
            'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.10'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @ Matt, You have to add MySQL configuration class to establish connection through your mysql-connector-java client. And check whether if it is MySQL driver jar is added in your class path.

Comment: I was hoping to use the embedded database for JPA testing... @PraveenKumar

Comment: you need to explicitly set the embedded database in your class path.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

We don't provide an embedded database by default. By default `DataJpaTest` replaces your `DataSource` with an embedded database but you don't have one.

So, if you want to test with MySQL, replace your test as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
final public class MyRepositoryTest {
}
```

If you want to use an in-memory database for those tests, you need to add one to the test classpath. Add this to your gradle file

```
testCompile('com.h2database:h2')
```

Comment: If instead of wanting to provide the AutoConfigureTestDatabase, can i specify this in a properties file?

i.e spring.test.database.connection: H2

Comment: Well you need to tell boot to not override your datasource so that annotation is required. Once you've done that you're free to configure the datasource any way you want. If you want more details, I'd create a seperate issue

Comment: Also, I've [create an issue in our tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7797) as I am wondering if we couldn't do something smarter here. Feel free to subscribe for updates or share your toughts on what Spring Boot should do in such situation.

Comment: Thanks yes i'll subscribe, it'll be interesting to see the discussion

Comment: @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)

Answer (score 3):

You could also configure this via application properties

```yaml
spring:
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this before your class.

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
```

it will run for sure.